# Associate two tables in a PowerBI Report

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm building a user-requested report. The user would like to see two tables that are almost identical, the only difference being the filtering, and would like the filtering to be automatic. Both tables contain, e.g., username | value | value ; Month is not included in the tables (although it can be if necessary for some reason).

The user would like to filter table 1 by "Month", where month is an integer, and have table 2 display results for the same username, but filtered by "Month-1."

The tables are direct representations of the data, not summarized in any way; that is, the original data table that I'm working from contains columns username | Month | value | value , etc. This is obviously not the greatest use for Power BI, but alas.

I created a calculated column PrevMonth to allow me to filter by Month-1. I've also created a separate data table containing exact duplicates of username, Month, and PrevMonth, in case that helped me to set up the filtering, but that's really only added confusion for me.

My next step is to create bookmarks for each desired filter state, but I am absolutely a novice with PowerBI; I bet there are better solutions and I'd love to learn.

- Is there any kind of VLOOKUP/index matching within a PBI *report*?
- Is it possible for me to sync two slicers (not using the Sync Slicers functionality since that won't work for my needs here, unless I'm mistaken), or a slicer and filter, such that when a user selects an option, the connected slicer/filter updates as well, but to a specific/formula-produced value?
- Is there some way I can build this out using measures? I tried to create a calculated column to obtain user input (and then learned calculated columns don't interact with report user input).

Thanks very much in advance for any suggestions/ideas/tips/resources!

Comment: Narrow down and refine your question to be for a specific ask/question. What is working, what isn't working, what you have tried, code, etc...